# Force ActiveResource to not convert complex object from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activeresource

The [ActiveResource docs](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) states that:

> Any complex element (one that contains other elements) becomes its own object:

```
# With this response:
# {"id":1,"first":"Tyler","address":{"street":"Paper St.","state":"CA"}}
#
# for GET http://api.people.com:3000/people/1.json
#
tyler = Person.find(1)
tyler.address  # => <Person::Address::xxxxx>
```

Since an attribute on the object I'm retrieving is a RGeo object that is supposed be be JSON, how do I request that this attribute is not converted. So the above would become:

```
tyler = Person.find(1)
tyler.address  # => {"street":"Paper St.","state":"CA"}
```

Comment: store adress as `serialize hash`

Comment: @Sontya If i understand you correctly, that would require changing the external API, which isn't an option.

Comment: but `person` is your model right?

Comment: Yes it is, BTW it would be a lot simple if you put your comment as an answer (a full one, not 5 words)

Answer (score 0):

TRy defining it as `serialize` Hash

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

    serialize :address, Hash
end
```

It will then treat `address` field as `Hash`

@object.address should return you, `key` `value` pair